# Azure Devops - How to access a variable group variable within another variable

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

The following Patch variable works perfectly when setup using the variables functionality within a Pipeline:

- Major = 1
- crmRelease = 91
- Minor = 0
- Patch = $[counter(format('{0}.{1}.{2}', variables['major'], variables['crmRelease'], variables['minor']), 030)

Result (on first run) = 1.91.0.30

However, when moving this to a Variable Group, whilst the Major, CrmRelase, and Minor variables are ok, the Patch variable isn't valid and fails. Must you reference Variable Group variables in a different way?

Comment: May I know what’s the status of this? Does below could help you on puzzle solved?

Answer (score 0):

> Must you reference Variable Group variables in a different way?

The issue for `Patch` does not been parsed is not relevant with the reference way to variable which stored at variable group. It just because the **function parse** does not supported in Variable group.

For further analysis, here let's do 2 tests(the first one is failed to get `Patch` value, but the second one can succeed).

One is put all of them into `Variable group`.

The another is putting `Major`, `crmRelease`, `Minor` into `Variable group`, but **  ** make `Patch` in `Variables`.

[image]

---

Here are their initial logs:

**Putting all of them into `Variable group`**:

[image]

**Only store `Patch` into Variables, but make others still in Variable group**:

[image]

You can see, only store Patch in Variables, the function of it can be parsed at compile time. For the one which store at Variable group, our system treat it as a normal value. We does not support the function parse process when it is from Variable group.

---

To make it not interrupt your build, please make sure the variable which contains the functions in it are located at **Variables** instead of **Variable group**.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this Merlin. I believe I still have a problem with this solution given my specific scenario. Let me explain. I'm packaging source code in my build pipeline and setting the package version. On completion of the build pipeline, I will be releasing the packages to numerous environments using a release pipeline. The reason I wanted this all to be handled globally is so I can retrieve the correct version number in the release pipeline. If I handle the patch variable locally, I can't guarantee they will be aligned between pipelines e.g. if a build fails and needs to be rerun